# Evaluate(?) $\int_{-2}^2 \sqrt{1-z^2} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I was asked by a wondering soul a question to find the value of the following expression
$$\int_{-2}^2 \sqrt{1-z^2} dz$$

I'm thinking of viewing this as a line integral on the complex plane, so for the intervals that $1-z^2$ is negative I think we have to choose one of the possible values of $\sqrt{1-z^2}$. But which one? Or before that, is this expression well-defined in the first place?

This is not a homework problem, just that I got curious and needed advice, so please feel free to share any idea.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's simply not well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

I would write the integral as follows:

$\displaystyle\int_{-2}^2\sqrt{1-z^2}dz=2\int_0^2\sqrt{1-z^2}dz=2\left(\int_0^1\sqrt{1-z^2}dz+\int_1^2\sqrt{1-z^2}dz\right)$.

For the second integral,

$\displaystyle\int_1^2\sqrt{1-z^2}dz=\int_1^2i\sqrt{z^2-1}dz$.

From there, trig substitution.

Comment: And why not $\sqrt{1-z^2} = -i\sqrt{z^2-1}$? It's the crux of the question. There's no preferred square root.

Comment: The integral as ill-defined as any procedure requiring one to pick a specific branch of a root function. The question can still be answered acknowledging this.

Comment: @nik Hmm, good point.  I would guess, since otherwise as you note the integral is not well defined, that that the square root of a negative real number is assumed to be the positive one.